# How to group elements inside select element inside React JS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-add-custom-option-64bes?file=/src/index.js) is a codesandbox url for the working demo of the grouping of elements with react.

So my requirement is that once the user clicks on the drop down, the user can see the list of items which are grouped.

1. In this list is only one **Group 1**, so the list Group 1 is
   coming but also one group is coming as **undefined** How can I
   remove the **undefined** as group inside the drop down list and
   whatever items are inside the **undefined** should be give some
   padding-right.
2. I have already given the style **mycustomselect** inside
   **style.css** but it still takes the default style. I want to remove the color green which is coming as the default.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: do you want to remove the items of the undefined group or include them in group 1?

Comment: While the link to the demo is nice, your post must include all relevant code within the body of the question itself. Read more about [mcve]

Comment: Okay. @ryanyuyu , I got what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `startDatePurchaseBehavior` contains items missing the propery `optgroup`. Your `for each` loop over that object then uses `undefined` when it can't find the property as the object key. This is where it happens:

```
 if (!groupedOptions[option.optgroup]) groupedOptions[option.optgroup] = [];
```

In order to fix it, make sure that every object in the array has the prop `optgroup`, like `optgroup: "Group 1"` for all items in one array or another key for the items in two.

I could not find `mycustomselect` inside style.css, but you can fix your problem using this id selector:

```
#cars {
  color: unset;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove that undefined you can put a condition on the name and you can choose a name that will be displayed instead of undefined

```
startDatePurchaseBehavior.forEach(option => {
          let val = option.optgroup
          if(!val){
            val = "No Group"
          }
          if (!groupedOptions[val]) groupedOptions[val] = [];
          groupedOptions[val].push({
            value: option.value,
            text: option.text
          });
        });
```